# What's the best way of synchronizing data between decoupled systems?

Tags: synchronization, eai, application-integration

I have let's say 2 (but they'll become more in the future) fully decoupled systems: system A and system B.

Let's say every piece of information on each system has an informationID. There's nothing stopping the informationID to be the same on different systems. What univocally identifies a piece of information across all systems is a Source-informationID pair.

Let's say I need to export a piece of information from System A to system B. I then want to export the same piece of information from System B and re-import it into System A and I  need to be able to recognize that's the same piece of information.

What's the best way of doing this in people's experience?

This is what I am thinking to do:

1. Setup a message bus between the
   systems with message queues.
2. Setup endpoints for each system
   that will monitor changes and
   generate commands wrapped into
   messages that will be pumped
   into queues (for example
   when a piece of information is
   created/deleted/updated).
3. Assign ranks to the endpoints
   relative to create/delete/update
   commands in order no to rely on
   system names but only on a general
   hierarchy - so that each system
   doesn't need to know about the
   others.
4. Assign a treshold on
   update/delete/create command to each
   endpoint so that commands not
   meeting the treshold requirement
   will be filtered out and not
   processed

This won't solve the fact that I still need to carry around originalSource+originalSourceID though.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I guess that the "same" information can be changed, otherwise, you would not need to reimport it, would you?

Comment: yes it can be edited create deleted everywhere - but I need to keep track of what's what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has been addressed by EAI (Enterprise Application Integration) vendors like [Tibco](http://tibco.com/) and [webMethods](http://www.softwareag.com/Corporate/products/wm/default.asp) (now part of Software AG).  I've never used Tibco before, but I've used webMethods to solve these kind of problems so I'll just focus on webmethods.  For example, in an enterprise, data about employees could reside in both Active Directory and PeopleSoft.  webMethods could be used to ensure changes, additions, deletes in one system (application) will be reflected in the other in real time.  In some other organization, data about employees could also be in an Oracle or SQL Server database.  Again, not a problem.  These EAI tools like webMethods can talk to a wide variety of back-ends.  webMethods is not limited to a single source and a single target, but because it has a publish-subscribe architecture, data from a single source can flow to multiple interested targets who subscribe to a particular piece of information.  Guaranteed delivery and may other features can be found in these products.  Back to the employee example, ultimately if one does it right, at any given time, all systems and applications in an enterprise can contain the same information about the employees without any discrepancy.

So instead of doing programming in C# or Java, you'll be doing webMethods programming which is very much like a 4GL language.  I call it programming because there are still logic involved, loop, if then else, branch, variables, packages, etc but it's very procedure oriented, i.e. no concept of OOP at all.

These EAI tools are built with limited purposes in mind and one of the purposes is to synchronize data between disparate systems in an enterprise easily.  And they do their job very well.

The drawback is these tools cost a lot of money.  Companies often have a long-term strategy before investing in these tools.

Answer (score 4):

As somebody already wrote, this sounds like a typical EAI problem. Even if EAI tools used to be expensive, now there is a wide choice of free, open-source tools. Below a list of the ones I like most

1. [OpenESB](http://open-esb.org/)
2. [Mule](http://www.mulesource.org/)
3. [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/home.html)
4. [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/)

My favorite is OpenESB, I know it best, it has a full IDE (Netbeans), optional support from a big vendor and a [huge amount of additional components](https://open-esb.dev.java.net/Components.html). For its simplicity and effectiveness I then love Apache Camel, but you can try some of those and decide which one works better for you. Then you can even decide to buy support services for all of those.

Answer (score 2):

We're doing pretty much exactly the sort of A -> B -> A thing that you describe.  We initially considered trying to have all the A,B,C etcs being peers, but that was too hard, so we now designate one as the primary, and the others the replica.  It's still easy enough to get stuff from one replica to another, but via the primary.

It's all done over web services - datasets go up and down from replica to primary and vice versa, and the replica runs the export on itself, and calls the import on the primary.  It then tells the primary to do an export, and runs the import on itself.

So the code is identical on each system.  It's only the replicas that call home.

The export and import processes tell the relevant business objects to do all their listing and saving stuff, since they already know how to instantiate and persist themselves from DataRows.

It's not a many-tens-of-transactions-per-second architecture, but it works, and can achieve nearly real time synchronisation.

We haven't improved on the Source/Id uniqueness, by the way :)

Comment: sounds like a good option - one of my main worries is the Source-Id uniqueness though!

Answer (score 2):

This is hugely simplified if you assign each piece of information a GUID.  If you need to keep track of source and other IDs, that's fine, but the information shuold always travel with its assigned GUID.

When a machine sees that piece of information again, it'll see the GUID and associate it with the existing data, and then you can decide what to do.  But you already know it's the same data piece - just better traveled.

Keep in mind that GUIDs are created in such a manner that each machine will create its own and they won't conflict (for all practical intents and purposes) with the GUIDs created on another machine, or the same machine at a different time.

This is one of the bigger reasons GUIDs were created.

-Adam

Comment: sounds like my GUID could be source + sourceID

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some specific limitation in the system design preventing this, I'd suggest factoring out the shared/sharable information into a separate DB that the other two can either reference or just replicate locally. Then you don't need the dual-element key nor any elaborate ESB contraption...

Comment: this is the Big-DB approach - which is an option I am looking into. 
It has its drawbacks though with regards to the fact that it could get messy soon enough.